# How javascript prevent duplicate mouseover function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some html div with same class name ('test')  and also a jQuery function which is working when .test hover. How I can stop function working until another div hover again?

```
<script>
$(".test").mouseover('hover', function(event) {
    console.log('hover');});
</script>
<html>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: You can start by removing `'hover'`, and then use `mouseout`, which is the opposite, to undo whatever changes you've made. I'd reccommend using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead though.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/3w87wdyu/1/

```js
$(".test").mouseenter(function(event) {
  console.log('hover');
}).mouseleave(function(event){
  console.log('mouse out');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">test 1</div>
<div class="test">test 2</div>
<div class="test">test 3</div>
<div class="test">test 4</div>
```

Please use `mouseenter` & `mouseleave`.
Don't use `hover` inside `mouseover`, doesn't make sense..

Hope this will help you.